# front and back Proposal for iterators Library

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, standards, c++17

In C++17 the [iterator library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) received [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), [`empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/empty), and [`data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data) allowing statically constructed arrays to behave like containers.

But I don't see a `front` or `back` function in the iterator library, which was added to the other containers in C++14: http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=front&button=

Is this something that has been proposed?

Comment: It is better to ask such a question at isocpp.org.

Comment: Isn't this something you could find out searching [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/)?

Comment: @NathanOliver Am I missing the search functionality there? I'm sure there's some Google-Fu that would let me accomplish some sort of depth first search... I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow A good suggestion. I've never posted over there to be honest, but maybe it's time to change that. Interestingly I found [this](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/std-discussion/front/std-discussion/eJdDI2q1xKg/ceTNszqbBwAJ) by searching the forum.

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes it would require google foo.  You could do something like `site:http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/ search term(s)`

Comment: @NathanOliver By searching with `std::front` or `std::back` for my "search term" I am able to find N4017. But I got more information from [searching the forum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265718/front-and-back-proposal-for-iterators-library?noredirect=1#comment60159875_36265718). Namely information that this had been thrown out of C++17, and there is currently no attempt to renter it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[N4017](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4017.htm) originally proposed `front`/`back`.

The Library Evolution Working Group voted to remove `front`/`back`:

> Do we want non-member front(), back()?

```
SF F N A SA
0  6 5 3 1
```

[[Source](https://issues.isocpp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30#c1)]

As a result N4107 was revised to [N4155](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4155.htm) and has been accepted sans `front`/`back`.

As of 02/18/16 `front`/`back` have not been reproposed: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/eJdDI2q1xKg/discussion